# determining the average colour of a given circular sample of an image?

Tags: python, image-processing

What I am trying to achieve is similar to photoshop/gimp's eyedropper tool: take a round sample of a given area in an image and return the average colour of that circular sample.

The simplest method I have found is to take a 'regular' square sample, mask it as a circle, then reduce it to 1 pixel, but this is very CPU-demanding (especially when repeated millions of times).

A more mathematically complex method is to take a square area and average only the pixels that fall within a circular area within that sample, but determining what pixel is or isn't within that circle, repeated, is CPU-demanding as well.

Is there a more succinct, less-CPU-demanding means to achieve this?

Comment: Creating a circular mask isn’t _that_ CPU demanding. Are you using numpy to do these numerical operations? If not, do so. Are you actually stuck with anything?

Comment: Just numpy? Okay, will give that a go, thanks.
No, not -stuck- per se, but wondering if there's something better out there... and it's been a while since I've done anything demanding in Python, and I might be re-inventing an already-existing wheel (that I could not find, all the same).

Comment: `skimage.draw.circle()` gives you the coordinates of all points within a circle... hint, hint... https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.circle

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little example of `skimage.draw.circle()` which doesn't actually draw a circle but gives you the coordinates of points within a circle which you can use to index Numpy arrays with.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imsave
from skimage.draw import circle

# Make rectangular canvas of mid-grey
w, h = 200, 100
img = np.full((h, w), 128, dtype=np.uint8)

# Get coordinates of points within a central circle
Ycoords, Xcoords = circle(h//2, w//2, 45)

# Make all points in circle=200, i.e. fill circle with 200
img[Ycoords, Xcoords] = 200

# Get mean of points in circle
print(img[Ycoords, Xcoords].mean())      # prints 200.0

# DEBUG: Save image for checking
imsave('result.png',img)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there's a more succinct way to go about it, but:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import imageio as ioimg # as scipy's i/o function is now depreciated
from skimage.draw import circle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# base sample dimensions (rest below calculated on this). 
# Must be an odd number.
wh = 49
# tmp - this placement will be programmed later
dp = 500

#load work image (from same work directory)
img = ioimg.imread('830.jpg')
# convert to numpy array (droppying the alpha while we're at it)
np_img = np.array(img)[:,:,:3]
# take sample of resulting array
sample = np_img[dp:wh+dp, dp:wh+dp]

#==============
# set up numpy circle mask
## this mask will be multiplied against each RGB layer in extracted sample area

# set up basic square array
sample_mask = np.zeros((wh, wh), dtype=np.uint8)
# set up circle centre coords and radius values
xy, r = math.floor(wh/2), math.ceil(wh/2)
# use these values to populate circle area with ones
rr, cc = circle(xy, xy, r)
sample_mask[rr, cc] = 1
# add axis to make array multiplication possible (do I have to do this)
sample_mask = sample_mask[:, :, np.newaxis]

result = sample * sample_mask
# count number of nonzero values (this will be our median divisor)
nz = np.count_nonzero(sample_mask)

sample_color = []
for c in range(result.shape[2]):
    sample_color.append(int(round(np.sum(result[:,:,c])/nz)))


print(sample_color) # will return array like [225, 205, 170]
plt.imshow(result, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting circle-sample]
Perhaps asking this question here wasn't necessary (it has been a while since I've python-ed, and was hoping that some new library had been developed for this since), but I hope this can be a reference for others who have the same goal.

This operation will be performed for every pixel in the image (sometimes millions of times) for thousands of images (scanned pages), so therein are my performance issue worries, but thanks to numpy, this code is pretty quick.

Comment: The above is working, but when iterating over the source image (pixel by pixel), it's -deathly- slow (one hour for a 2500 x 4500px image).

Comment: Looks like it's time to give cython a go, iterating in increments of 10 pixels (or the like, depending on original image size).